# Why is Swift compiler complaining about circular reference when I comment out seemingly unrelated code?

Tags: swift, enums, circular-reference

Creating a brand new macOS Command Line Tool project in Xcode Version 13.3 (13E113), and replacing the contents of `main.swift` with the following code:

```swift
import Foundation

enum StructA {
    // case case1(value: StructB)
    case case2(expr: StructB)
}

indirect enum StructB {
    case case3
    case case4(expr: StructB)
}
```

Results in the following compile-time error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: circular reference
/Users/alextj/projects/TestProject/main.swift:8:15: note: through reference here
indirect enum StructB {
              ^
<unknown>:0: note: through reference here
```

***However***, if you uncomment the `case1` line, then the circular reference error goes away!

So the following code compiles without errors:

```swift
import Foundation

enum StructA {
    case case1(value: StructB)
    case case2(expr: StructB)
}

indirect enum StructB {
    case case3
    case case4(expr: StructB)
}
```

Why?

Why does commenting out `case1` cause a circular reference?

Comment: Another funny thing is that if you rename `expr` in either `case2` or `case4`, the error goes away.

Comment: I have a similar problem and don't know why ??

Answer (score 0):

I did the following steps which helped me resolve the circular reference
after updating to `Xcode 13.3.1`:

1- Clean project.

2- Clean derived data.

3- Change project Build Setting `SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE` from Incremental to the Whole Module.

https://forums.swift.org/t/strange-enum-circular-reference-error-in-xcode-13-3/56721/2

Comment: Thanks for the answer Amr! I tried your steps, also on Xcode 13.3.1, but I still get the circular reference error :(

Comment: it's one of the weird errors i have ever seen, I hope you resolved soon. 
sorry I couldn't help match since it's not available anymore in my project